# Convert PPT to JPG using Jodconverter and openoffice.org

Tags: openoffice.org, jodconverter

Hi everybody, 
            I successfully installed java, tomcat, jodconverter and openoffice in my ubuntu system and converted the PPT to SWF and PPT to PDF. Everything went fine but I didn't see any option to convert ppt to jpg or png in the web app provided by jod converter.

can anybody help me to convert the power point presentations into JPG's or PNG's by jodconverter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use imageMagick to convert pdf to image

Comment: have you seen, what is my problem??

Comment: use jodconverter: ppt->pdf; 
then use imageMagick: pdf->jpg